# Only one file on my site is returning 404, all others work

Tags: php, http, twilio

We recently moved our main domain to point to a Shopify site. To allow Twilio to access some endpoints on the old site I created a subdomain and pointed it to the AWS alb for the old site. The site itself loads great.

The problem is one of the two files we've been using for Twilio endpoints now returns a 404, but one of them works perfectly.

The one that works is like: `https://legacy.mysite.com/includes/Common/Twilio/twilio-status-call-back.php`.

The errant one that we receive SMS from Twilio is: `https://legacy.mysite.com/includes/Common/Twilio/process-sms.php` - the returns the 404

Any idea why only one file would not work?

Comment: Check permissions and casing of the filename on the server matches the specified URL filename casing.

Comment: everything is the same as it was when it was working except for the URL

Comment: what does `ls - l ./includes/Common/Twilio` output? Any kind of redirects going on in `process-sms.php`?